# How to bind new rows to ASP.NET MVC 4 WebGrid with Model on Client side and enable Validations (DataAnnotations) of the WebGrid on Client Side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am working on ASP.NET WebGrid for displaying a Collection of objects and allow adding new objects to the collection.

On the view with Webgrid I have a Add button using which I dynamically add a new row based on atemplate and append to the grid.

I need help on,

> 1) How to bind the new rows with the WebGrid Model on the Client side.
>   2) How to enable validations on the WebGrid with DataAnnotations
>   validations defined on the Model.

Following is the code,

```
public class TestObject
    {
        public virtual int Id
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        [Display( Name = "Codee")]
        public virtual string Code
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "Required")]
        [Display( Name = "Description")]
        public virtual string Description
        {
            get;
            set;
        }       
    }
```

Index.html

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    <div class="body-container">
    <table class="form-grid">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button"  onclick="AddRow(); return false;">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="form-grid">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div id="partialregion">
                    @Html.Partial("_ListView", Model)
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table id="newTemplate" style="display: none;">
        <tr class="item">
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" id="cId" /></td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="code" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="description" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

_ListView.HTML

```
@model IEnumerable<TestObject>
<div id="testGrid">
    @{

        var grid = new WebGrid(null, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "testGrid" , canSort: false);
        grid.Bind(Model);

        @MvcHtmlString.Create(
        @grid.GetHtml(
        tableStyle: "grid-table",
          columns: grid.Columns(
                    grid.Column("",header:"",format : @<input id="hiddenId" type="hidden" value="@item.Id" />),
                    grid.Column("Code", header: "Code", format: @<input type="text" id="mCode" value="@item.Code" />),        
                    grid.Column("Description", header: "Description", format: @<input type="text" id="mDesc" value="@item.Description" />)
        )).ToString())
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to anwser:

`1) How to bind the new rows with the WebGrid Model on the Client side.`

I recommend you persist it on server-side and reload your grid, using a PartialView with jquery `load` method.

`2) How to enable validations on the WebGrid with DataAnnotations validations defined on the Model.`

DataAnnotations validate your model, but when it is on a form, not in a grid. To Enabled the Client-Side validation on forms, you have to change yoru web.config file adding these appSettings:

```
<appSettings>
    <!-- others -->

    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />

</appSettings>
```

And also remember to include the jquery validation and unobtrusive javascript files on your Layout (or Views):

```
<script src='@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.js")'></script>
<script src='@Url.Content("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")'></script>
```